# XSL: How to select substrings between multiple repeating ~ characters as separator

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Please help.  Need to be able to select/extract strings located between identical repeating ~ characters.

Example: The dog escaped ~ from the fence ~ and ran across the road ~ into traffic, but did not ~ get hurt thankfully.  We are ~ very happy the dog is safe.

FOLLOWING this format  AAA=BBBBB=CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC=D=FFFFF=GG=H, tried to apply the below method, but unable to extract using this approach:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
            substring-after ($vari, , '=')
           , '=')"/>
```

For BBBBB
Or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
             substring-after ( substring-after ($vari,  '='),  '=')
             , '=')"/>
```

For CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by  "*unable to extract using this approach*"? If `$vari` contains the string `AAA=BBBBB=CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC=D=FFFFF=GG=H`, then your second expression returns `CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC` (your first expression has an extra comma). If you're seeing something else, post a **complete** example that would allow us to reproduce the problem. -- P.S. I am not sure how the example with `" ~ "` as the separator helps here.

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="t">
    <xsl:param name="pIndex" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vToken" select=
    "substring-before(substring(concat(.,'~'), $pIndex+1), '~')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vnewIndex" select="$pIndex+string-length($vToken)+1"/>
    <token>
      <xsl:value-of select="$vToken"/>
    </token>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()[not($vnewIndex >= string-length(.))]">
      <xsl:with-param name="pIndex" select="$vnewIndex"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<t>The dog escaped ~ from the fence ~ and ran across the road ~ into traffic, but did not ~ get hurt thankfully. We are ~ very happy the dog is safe.</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<token>The dog escaped </token>
<token> from the fence </token>
<token> and ran across the road </token>
<token> into traffic, but did not </token>
<token> get hurt thankfully. We are </token>
<token> very happy the dog is safe.</token>
```